# New responsive site - best minimal approach?

Tags: frameworks

I'm re-building a static business site for myself. I've spent a month learning and working with many frameworks (Bootstrap, Foundation, various grids, layouts, themplates, etc.). Most go way overboard (Wordpress), cause slow loading times and are hard to adapt. And, I really don't have time to learn sass, less, etc - though I wish I could (and maybe will).

I'm looking for anyone's advice here - what would you use? No CMS needed, accordions/tabs/sliders would be nice for better ordering/gallery pages, pretty straightforward layout as seen in my link below. I do realize this is a whole new build/design world now, but just in the past month, I've been approached 4 times by folks like me who also wonder what to do...and they're either giving up or going with Wordpress.

Though reticent to admit that my site still uses tables (gack!! - hey I have 2 jobs...), [here's the link.](http://www.mountainscenejewelry.com)

Sorry, but it just seems like you can either take an easy way with all the bloat, or it's really hard. Will this all be different a year from now (especially the gap in between)?  Just frustrated...

Thanks so much!
~Lauren

Comment: Do you have a design? Typically you choose the framework and the tools after you've planned the site out.

Comment: if someone asked me who had no experience "not saying you have no experience just a example" but if the person had no experience and had to update your site to a cleaner design i would either point them to weebly.com website builder or wordpress between easy and clean design the site can also have a very nice mobile design for mobile phone browsers.

Comment: Blender: yes, the whole thing sketched/wireframed and nearly the same as the old site - just responsive.

Comment: Rezand - thanks - weebly for sure not, and Wordpress is overkill for a static site. Thanks to you both, though!

Answer (score 0):

What are your problems with Bootstrap (or Foundation, I suppose -- just replace "Less" below with "Sass")?

You mentioned being opposed to learning Less -- but you don't have to use it yourself to use Bootstrap (BS): just pull in the CSS files and use BS classes in your markup. If you need more styling, write your own CSS file and pull it in separately.

I thought Bootstrap might be a good solution for you because it provides the UI components that you would like (you mention accordion/tabs/sliders) and it is pretty easy to follow along with the examples in the BS documentation, reproducing the required markup. Depending on how much you want to customize the styling, you could produce a nice, functional static site pretty quickly.